# Displaying data of two tables on the same web page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. Currently I am working on a small project as practice and I am trying to display data of two tables on the same web page.
I tried to use`$this->db->join();` 
in codeigniter but it does not work for me. I was wondering is there other options that I can explore of displaying two table data on a same web page?

I am also posting my join method that I have tried - maybe you can tell me I did something wrong?

**model**

```
  $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*');
    $this->db->from('tblanswers');
    $this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'left'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

The problem with this join function I have that it only displays one table but not the other. I used the  `print_r($data['query']); die()` to checked this it only returns the tblanswer not both.

**EDIT**

Table structure:

**credentials**

```
+--------------+------+-------------+-------+-------+
| cid(PRIMARY) | name | second_name | phone | email |
+--------------+------+-------------+-------+-------+
```

**tblanswers**

```
+-------------------+--------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| answerid(PRIMARY) | userid | questionid | answerA | answerB | answerC |
+-------------------+--------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok so first of all your table **MUST** have relational data to perform a join

```
return $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*')
                      ->join('credentials cred', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'LEFT')
                      ->get('tblanswers')
                      ->result_object()
```

so this will perform a query fetching the data from the **credentials** table where the **answerid field = the cid field*

E.G

```
  SELECT * FROM tblanswers
  JOIN credentials ON credentials.cid = tblanswers.answerid
```

**EDIT**

seems like you dont event need to use a join for what you want you could simply go

```
 return $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*')
                ->from('tblanswers, credentials')
                ->get()
                ->result_object();
```

because it doesnt seem like you have any relational data between the two but for example you could get all questions relating to that awnser by going

```
return $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,questions.*')
                      ->join('questions AS q', 'tblanswers.questionid = q.question_id', 'LEFT')
                      ->get('tblanswers')
                      ->result_object()
```

Comment: can u explain more about the relational data ? tnx for your help

Comment: @EdvinasLiutvaitis ok edited the question hope it explains alittle bit more but basicly its only going to select from the credentials table where **tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid** i also have no idea of the layout of your database so i am not shure if you even require a join for this kind of project

Comment: it will only select the columns that have the same name in the two tables ? i will edit my question and will put up my table structure

Comment: @EdvinasLiutvaitis No not the same name the same value like for example like 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559730/selecting-from-the-same-table-more-than-once-in-the-same-query
there the ex_inv_id will allow me to get the invoice related to that exhibit by using the value of that id because it is **relational data** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database

Comment: @EdvinasLiutvaitis There Edited the answer for you to maybe understand alittle bit more of how the join function works

Comment: tnx Dark-Reaper- u are right i daunt need join method it works fine with out it and u are correct i red you links and i daunt have any relational data tnx so much for your help.