# mysql join for specific rows only

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

i've three tables

**comments table**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
id    |    commented_by       | comment          | commented_by
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |    asdf156df5s4fd     | student comment  |  student
2     |    klsdfjklsdfno      | student comment  |  student
3     |    jafkadfjlkdnvwa    | teacher comment  |  teacher
4     |    adsjflandsfinndfs  | student comment  |  student
5     |    dsf5614dsf8wef4    | teacher comment  |  teacher
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**teacher table**

---

```
id    |    teacher_id       | teacher_name | teaches
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |    jafkadfjlkdnvwa  | abc cde      |  maths
2     |    dsf5614dsf8wef4  | egc kjl      |  science
.
.
.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**student table**

---

```
id    |    student_id        | student_name |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |    asdf156df5s4fd    | student_1    |
2     |    klsdfjklsdfno     | student_2    |
3     |    adsjflandsfinndfs | student_3    |
.
.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

now, what we wish is `mysql join` which could return something like this

---

```
id    |    comment_id         | comment_by |  name | teaches
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |    asdf156df5s4fd     | student    |  student_1   | null
2     |    klsdfjklsdfno      | student    |  student_2   | null
3     |    jafkadfjlkdnvwa    | teacher    |  abc cde     | maths
4     |    adsjflandsfinndfs  | student    |  student_3   | null
5     |    dsf5614dsf8wef4    | teacher    |  egc kjl     | science
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

unable to find the exact query with which we can achieve this with codeigniter active records

Comment: can you post some code of what have you tryed? btw try looking at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219132/displaying-data-of-two-tables-on-the-same-web-page

Comment: You'll have to provide more information about what you're trying to do here.  I personally don't see how you get these results from those 3 tables.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter basically a post where we are going to show comments, but with comment from teacher it is going to include subjects they teach but not for students

Comment: You need to normalize your table

Comment: @Oncodeeater how to do that, suggest me, never heard of it

Comment: It depends, is this all attributes you are using(there are not any more tables to come?)? Can one teacher teach only one class or more?

Answer (score 0):

It's real dirty table scheme but this is the query you want:

```
SELECT 
  c.id, 
  commented_by as comment_id, 
  commented_by, 
  IF(commented_by = 'student', student_name, teacher_name) as name, 
  teaches
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN teacher t
  ON t.teacher_id = c.commented_by
 AND c.commented_by = 'teacher'
LEFT JOIN student s
  ON s.student_id = c.commented_by
 AND c.commented_by = 'student'
```

A better table scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  comment_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  student_id INT,
  teacher_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (comment_id)
);

CREATE TABLE teachers (
  teacher_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  teacher_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  teacher_subject VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (teacher_id)
);

CREATE TABLE students (
  student_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  student_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
);

SELECT 
  comments.*, 
  IF(student_id IS NOT NULL, student_name, teacher_name) as name, 
  teacher_subject
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN teachers USING(teacher_id)
LEFT JOIN students USING(student_id)
```

Comment: what could be the better way of designing table schema ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join student and teacher table:

```
select id, comment_id as comment_by , commented_by, 
( case when commented_by = 'teacher' THEN teacher_name else student_name ) AS name, teaches
from comments c left join teacher t ON t.teacher_id = c.commented_by left 
join student s ON s.student_id = c.commented_by
```