# I don't know how to write this query in Codeigniter's query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
SELECT a.tgl_kejadian,b.nama_bencana,a.alamat,c.nama_kelurahan,d.nama_kecamatan,a.kerugian,a.keterangan 
FROM data_kejadian a , data_bencana b, kelurahan c, kecamatan d       

WHERE a.id_bencana=b.id_bencana       

AND a.id_daerah=c.id_kelurahan 

AND c.id_kecamatan=d.id_kecamatan 

AND a.tgl_kejadian BETWEEN '$tanggal_awal' AND '$tanggal_akhir'
```

I want to make it clear in Codeigniter way but i still don't understand how to write it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying data of two tables on the same web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219132/displaying-data-of-two-tables-on-the-same-web-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$this->db->select('a.tgl_kejadian,b.nama_bencana,a.alamat,c.nama_kelurahan,d.nama_kecamatan,a.kerugian,a.keterangan')
          ->from('data_kejadian a , data_bencana b, kelurahan c, kecamatan d')
          ->where('a.id_bencana = b.id_bencana')
          ->where('a.id_daerah = c.id_kelurahan')
          ->where('c.id_kecamatan = d.id_kecamatan')
          ->where_between('a.tgl_kejadian', ['$tanggal_awal', '$tanggal_akhir']);
```